# looking for the proof of a formula ($\mathbb{R}^3$ vector product)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors

does anyone know how to prove the following formula for vector product?
$$(u\cdot\nabla)u=\nabla\frac{|u|^2}{2}-u\times(\nabla\times u).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the prove we need the Levi-Civita symbol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) and use the Einstein summation convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

The vector product is defined by $(u \times v)_i = \epsilon_{ijk} u_j v_k$.

Therefore the left side of the formula is
\begin{align*}
\left(\nabla \frac{|u|^2}{2} - u \times (\nabla \times u)\right)_i &= \partial_i \left( \frac{u_h u_h}{2} \right) - \epsilon_{ijk} u_j (\epsilon_{klm} \partial_l u_m) \\
&= u_h \partial_i u_h - \epsilon_{kij} \epsilon_{klm} u_j \partial_l u_m \\
&= u_h \partial_i u_h - (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl})u_j \partial_l u_m \\
&= u_h \partial_i u_h - \delta_{il}\delta_{jm}u_j \partial_l u_m + \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}u_j \partial_l u_m \\
&= u_h \partial_i u_h - u_j \partial_i u_j + u_j \partial_j u_i \\
&= (u_j \partial_j )u_i = \left((u \cdot \nabla)u \right)_i
\end{align*}

Therefore $\nabla \frac{|u|^2}{2} - u \times (\nabla \times u) = (u \cdot \nabla)u$.

In the second line I used the chain rule and the antisymmetry of $\epsilon$. For the next step I used the identity $\epsilon_{kij} \epsilon_{klm} = \delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}$ of the Levi-Civita symbol.

Comment: I have trouble getting line 5 from line 4. Basically I took 3 terms first, so $u_j\delta_{jm} u_m=u_j u_j$, then what remains is $\delta_{il}\partial_l(u_j u_j)$, why does this become $u_j\partial_i u_j$?

Comment: Is this because, if I sum up all those $i\ne l$ terms I get 0, and summing all $i=l$ terms I get 1, then sum the 0 and 1 parts together I ends up with $\partial_i u_j u_j$?

Comment: if i keep going with what I wrote above, for your second term line 4. Took $\delta_{im}u_j u_m=u_j u_j$, then $\delta_{jl}\partial_l(u_i u_j)$, summing all all $l\ne j$ terms I get 0, summing up all $l=j$ terms I get 1, then sum the two parts together I ends up with $\partial_j u_j u_i$ (same as $u_j\partial_j u_i$?

Comment: From line 4 to 5: You just plug in the definition of the delta-function: $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$, else it is zero. So $\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}u_j \partial_l u_m = u_j \partial_{i=l} u_{j=m}$.